# [Pattern]Keep transaction in a queue

Tags: .net, design-patterns

For the moment, when an exception occur, I show a message error to the user.
But I want, in this case, keep the transaction in a queue to retry again later.

Do you know if a pattern to resolve my problem exist ???

thanks,
Tkanos

Answer (score 1):

By 'transaction' I assume that you refer to an action undertaken against a data store, as opposed to ACID transactions.

In that case, the [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) pattern should fit you problem nicely.